# Set property WPF page programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have made 3 pages; Pages1.xaml, Pages2.xaml and Pages3.xaml. I have remove the `StartupUri` in the Application.xaml so I can decide which pages will be loaded first from the configuration settings (.INI).

At `Application_Startup`, I selecting from config

```
Select Case intPage
     Case 1
            Me.StartupUri = New System.Uri("Page1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)
     Case 2
            Me.StartupUri = New System.Uri("Page2.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)
     Case 3
            Me.StartupUri = New System.Uri("Page3.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)
End Select
```

Page will be loaded based from config. Now what I have problem now, is the page will be shown like Windows. Having minimize,maximize and close button. I have search on the internet, but most teach to Windows, not Pages.

Question: How to make the Pages; Maximize, WindowsStyle None, Topmost True and Cursor None programatically. Below are what I do on Application.xaml but its not work and still showing windows border:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type NavigationWindow}" TargetType="{x:Type NavigationWindow}">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowsNavigationUI" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Topmost" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="None"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Right now, what can I do in create new instance in Page1 is:

```
    Me.ShowsNavigationUI = False
    Me.Width = 768
    Me.Height = 1366
```

only. ShowsNavigationUI, Width and Height。

Comment: Can you set those same properties on the Window elements in PageX.xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Page** is intended to be shown inside a **Frame** or a **NavigationWindow**. I think it isn't a good idea to show your Pages as a Window. For both you can host the same XAML you just need to use the right container. And in the Windows you can easy change the Window-State to maximized. Hope I could help.

Comment: Yes..i have try change from page to windows. I set the page to tranparency with windows style to none.. and it's work..no more border.thanks!